# socket.io client not connected to azure server created in socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, azure

```
//this is my client code which is previously pointing to my local server which is on my Lan network.it work fine   
//my server code i post on azure machine and run it run fine 
//but it not connected to my below client 
var socket = io.connect('http://104.222.195.120:4000');// azure ip add
                socket.on('news', function (data) {//angular client for socket
                    $rootScope.top = JSON.parse(data);//top receive data
             $scope.$apply(function () {
                        // $scope.newCustomers.push(data.customer);
                        // $scope.a1 = data;
                    });
                });
```

//io.connect('http://104.222.195.120:4000') is need more than ip

Comment: Here is an article on Azure official site, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio/ which guides us how to create a socket.io application on Azure Web Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running your server in an Azure Web App, you're going to have issues because you're trying to listen on port 4000. Web Apps only allow for ports 80 and 443.

If you're running your server in an Azure VM, you have to open port 4000 to the outside world via network security group (or *endpoint* if doing a Classic VM deployment).

Comment: sir any link for that

Comment: Link for what? Azure web app port limits? Been like that since the introduction of Web Apps (originally called Websites).

Comment: sir i think my azure port is close i have to open for outside world and i don't found the procedure for it.