# Node.js works locally but returns "Bad request" remotely

Tags: node.js, azure

I created an app (Node.js + Express), run it locally. Then I created Node.js app at Azure and uploaded files through FTP. And then I stuck - how to run it?

I found kind of remote console in azure and installed all the packages from there. But when I tried to run the app: "npm start" I had only one line back: "**Bad request**". What does it mean? What to do with it?

The beginning of ./bin/www file:

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('goWeb:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

goWeb - is my app, mentioned in package.js.

UPD I changed port to 80 and now I have the error "Port 80 requires elevated privileges". I have no idea what to do next.
Thanks

Comment: You need to show some code. E.g. what does the `npm start` command do?

Comment: I don't know what it does on azure (I believe something else) but locally it goes to ./bin/www and run www file. But remotely - even if I run "node ./bin/www" I have the same result. And even if I run "node app.js" it returns the same.

Comment: Like @miparnisari said: You've shown no code, so it's kinda impossible to figure out what's going on. Just curious: What port is your app listening on?

Comment: The code is standard - I didn't create it, it was generated automatically (as for I used express) - I will update the post right now with the first part of ./bin/www file.

Comment: I think @DavidMakogon nailed it - you're listening on the wrong port! It should be port 80 (or 8080, can't remember)

Comment: Okay, let me try to change this port to 80 (or 8080) and see if it works. Why do you think the port is wrong? It's working locally, why shouldn't it work on azure app?

Comment: Azure Web Apps only support ports 80 and 443. I posted an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39996991/272109) about this. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36425811/272109), where I show how to properly read the port from the environment.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it! Now after I changed 3000 to 80 I have "Port 80 requires elevated privileges". What's wrong this time?

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I read your posts but I still don't know what to do. I don't have VM, my app is just "App service" in terms of Azure, and didn't find how I can say add endpoints because app doesn't have them. And I don't have any Network security group because of the same.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `app.js` file is not in `wwwroot` folder where the content is served by the web server [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) and you don't need to do `npm start` in Azure web apps.

You can take a look at my `wwwroot` structure, it looks like this:
[image]

You can also customize the path of the `app.js` file with the following lines in `web.config`.

```
<handlers>
    <!-- Indicates that the app.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
</handlers>
```

Comment: My app is running under Node.js, without any track of IIS, so I even don't have any web.config file.

Comment: Node.js applications deployed to `Azure App Services` are using the `iisnode` module to run and the `web.config` file will be automatically created when a `server.js` or `app.js` file as the entrance is put in the `wwwroot` directory.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are right! I didn't know about IIS. It sounds weird.